# Sub-reports won't render to file SSRS

Tags: c#, asp.net, reportviewer, reporting-services

I have several server reports with sub reports. My problem is that I want to save these as PDF documents to the server. I do so using:

```
ReportViewer.ServerReport.Render("PDF", null, out mimeType, out encoding,
   out extension, out streams, out warnings);
```

And then saving the resulting bytes to a file with the correct extension.

When I render in this way and then look at the resultant PDF there is just blank space where the sub-reports should be.

Weirdly I had forgotten to set a sub-report parameter from the parent on one attempt and the PDF contained a message altering me. When I added the parameter, re-uploaded the report, and tried to generate it again again I just got the blank space.

Comment: I would check your report sizes against the PDF page sizes; SSRS follows the page sizes you have set and I don't think it renders outsized reports because of the page breaking issues it would face.

Comment: I've made the sub report an inch smaller than the parent (and the sub-reports container in the parent). No luck unfortunately.

Comment: Even with the sub report as a 1x1 inch box with nothing but a line in it does not work.

Comment: @u07ch If the body size grows larger (because of the content) than the page size of the report, then the PDF renderer will generate additional pages (much like Excel when the sheet won't fit horizontally).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SSRS has behaved very weirdly for me in the past when *re-uploading reports where the parameters have changed*. You could try to:

- delete the report first, then **re-upload** the subreport? (same for main report)
- **temporarily duplicate** the sub-report with a new name, upload that and retry?
- check the Reporting Services **Web Frontend** and try to preview / export the report there?

Just as a small but important final question: have you checked that the **sub-reports aren't just *empty*** (and are rendering normally, but empty)? E.g. put a static textbox in it or something alike.

Comment: Yup that was it. Screwy parameters. Thanks.